# Using the YouTube V3 API to echo video ID's

Tags: php, linux, youtube-api

Sometime in October Google decided to make an undocumented change to their livestreaming service which has left me puzzled for months. After finally finding the issue I have began looking into the YouTube V3 API for a solution however I am starting to think this is not possible therefore I would really appreciate some feedback on what I am trying to achieve.

Currently, when livestreaming on YouTube you are given 3 privacy options;

- **Public** - You can embed via the channel ID meaning its persistent.
- **Unlisted** - You can only embed via the video ID which changes whenever you start a new stream.
- <strike>Private</strike>

When searching for a way to automate the process of obtaining a variable (video ID) of an unlisted video I came across the code below provided by YouTube (https://github.com/youtube/api-samples);

```
<?php

/**
* Library Requirements
*
* 1. Install composer (https://getcomposer.org)
* 2. On the command line, change to this directory (api-samples/php)
* 3. Require the google/apiclient library
*    $ composer require google/apiclient:~2.0
*/
if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
throw new \Exception('please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "' . __DIR__ .'"');
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

/*
* You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
* {{ Google Cloud Console }} <{{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}>
* For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
* <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
* Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
*/
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE_ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REPLACE_ME';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

// Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
$tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
die('The session state did not match.');
}

$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
try {
// Call the channels.list method to retrieve information about the
// currently authenticated user's channel.
$channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array(
'mine' => 'true',
));

$htmlBody = '';
foreach ($channelsResponse['items'] as $channel) {
// Extract the unique playlist ID that identifies the list of videos
// uploaded to the channel, and then call the playlistItems.list method
// to retrieve that list.
$uploadsListId = $channel['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];

$playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
'maxResults' => 50
));

$htmlBody .= "<h3>Videos in list $uploadsListId</h3><ul>";
foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {
$htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $playlistItem['snippet']['title'],
$playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']);
}
$htmlBody .= '</ul>';
}
} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
$htmlBody = sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
} catch (Google_Exception $e) {
$htmlBody = sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
}

$_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
} elseif ($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID == 'REPLACE_ME') {
$htmlBody = <<<END
<h3>Client Credentials Required</h3>
<p>
You need to set <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> and
<code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> before proceeding.
<p>
END;
} else {
$state = mt_rand();
$client->setState($state);
$_SESSION['state'] = $state;

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
$htmlBody = <<<END
<h3>Authorization Required</h3>
<p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Uploads</title>
</head>
<body>
<?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

The example above is fantastic, it works just as I need it to. When I navigate to /my_upload.php (source above) via a web browser I am able to login via OAuth to my YouTube account and print a list of video ID's that coincide with the videos I have uploaded. Funnily enough when I change the 'maxResults' option to 1 it will list the most recent video ID and if I am currently live streaming that video ID will be the most recent. As far as I am aware once you have authenticated once you do not need to re-authenticate however I am having issues authenticating from my backend server.

The system I would like to have in place involves using cron, I would for example have a bash script do the following;

```
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg -whatever -launch -parameters -I -need ### Launch the livestream
timeout 300 seconds ### Pause for 5 Minutes to allow YouTube to go live
curl/php path/to/my_uploads.php ### Run the php script to obtain video ID
```

Whenever the cron is scheduled it would launch the livestream then run the my_uploads.php script to obtain the video ID which would save in a .txt document ready to be echoed into the web player.

**So what's the issue?**

I have successfully managed to authenticate by going to the /my_uploads.php file in a browser however that does not authenticate the backend server, I am using VNC to connect to the backend server to authenticate. I thought this would be as simple as doing something like;

```
curl http://backendserverip/my_uploads.php -> Follow auth steps
```

But of course not, Google does not allow IP's to be used so for testing purposes I have edited the /etc/hosts file to reflect the following;

```
myserverip localhost.mydomain.com
```

Which does function fine according to what Google accept. Great, it should work now... Wrong. When I do the following;

```
curl http://localhost.mydomain.com/my_uploads.php (ignore index.php)
```

[image: a busy cat]

Visit the link as printed in the terminal;

[image: a busy cat]

I get an error stating "The session state did not match" which I am guessing is because the authentication URL was generated within the terminal and when I enter the link in the browser the headers and whatever else is different so for security its not allowing me to authenticate.

Surely there must be a way that my server is able to authenticate in order to access the API, surely I am doing something wrong as it makes absolutely no sense as to why this would even exist. If this was only for web based usage who in this world would access a third party site, login via OAuth to have their video data echoed. Why would they not just use YouTube directly?

What confuses me is, I have used VNC to connect to my server. Opened up firefox, navigated to the my_uploads.php file, autenticated and it works fine;

[image: a busy cat]

However when executing a command via the terminal/putty;

```
curl http://localhost.mydomain.com/my_uploads.php (ignore index.php)
```

I am forced to re-authenticate however I cannot do that via the terminal its not possible as far as I am aware.

Am I an idiot? Is this not even possible or am I doing the completely wrong thing here, I have spent the past 2 days trying to figure this out. I have learned a lot on the way but I am absolutely lost and I really do need some help here, thank you for your time and sorry for the lengthy post.